# Is the elision in the sentence "pour réfléchir qu'americans" correct?

Tags: grammaire, élision

I want to know if it is correct to make an elision in this sentence "pour réfléchir ***qu'americans*** en moyenne dorment moins que ce qu'ils ont fait dans le passé." or Should I write "que americains" instead?

Comment: Welcome to French Language Paul. Neither the on nor the other. Because you ave to use the definite article ***les** Américains* so the problem doesn't arise it is *que les Américains*. Other problems with your sentence though but since it incomplete difficult to say anything precise.

Comment: What are you trying to say actually with the phrase: pour réflechir qu'américains? To reflect that Americans on average sleep less than? Why are you using reflect here? Wouldn't it be: to show?

Comment: I realize that you are not asking about this, but if you were using “américain/e” as an adjective, especially in a comparison (aussi/moins/plus X qu’Y), an article would not be required and I think the elision would be acceptable (and perhaps preferable or even required), for example: “Même après 40 ans aux États-Unis, elle se sent plus française qu’américaine.”

Comment: The whole paragraph: "Experts généralement conseillent de sept à neuf heures par nuit pour adultes en santé. Les scientifiques qui étudient le sommeil disent, nouvelles lignes directrices sont nécessaires pour prendre en compte  une abondance de récente recherche dans ce domaine et pour réfléchir que les Américains en moyenne dorment moins que ce qu'ils ont fait dans le passé." What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans la phrase suivante, l'élision est correcte:

> L'homme moderne dort peu, peu importe sa nationalité. Aussi bien français **qu'américain**, un employé de bureau dort en moyenne trois heures par jour de moins qu'en 1930.
>
> The modern man does not sleep much, independently of his nationality. Whether French or American, an office worker sleeps on average three hours less than he did in 1930.

Attention à l'orthographe: il faut écrire « américains », avec un « é » (« e » accent aigu) et la terminaison « -ains », et non « americans ».

Comme @KarimDahmani et @Ctouw l'ont noté, votre phrase ne semble pas correctement construite, il faudrait plutôt écrire:

> Des études **laissent à penser** que **les** am**é**rica**i**ns dorment en moyenne moins que ce qu'auparavant
>
> Des études **montrent** que **les** am**é**rica**i**ns dorment en moyenne moins que par le passé.
>
> Des études **montrent** que **les** am**é**rica**i**ns dorment en moyenne moins que ce qu'ils **l'ont** fait par le passé.

Je pense qu'il faut inclure un « l' » dans la proposition « que ce qu'ils l'ont fait par le passé », bien que je n'en soie pas totalement certain. L'antécédent de « l' » dans ce cas serait le verbe « dormir ».

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing a vowel after "que", your have to do the elision. i.e. you should write "qu'americans". However, your sentence seems to be not correct. I don't know how you are using it in a complete sentence but we say "pour réfléchir que les américains en moyenne dorment moins que ce qu'ils ont fait dans le passé".

Comment: I think "think" in his sentence refers to "penser" and not "réfléchir". I guess his full sentence is something like "Des études laissent à penser que les américains dorment en moyenne moins qu'auparavant".